# Did they switch the neutral wire on accident? (1970)

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch

Replacing a ceiling fan in 1970 house on a slab - most power is run to the J box in the attic. But from my limited knowledge it looks like they switched the common and not the hot?

Q: Why would they do this? Standard practice in the 70's?

Q: Is it as easy as swapping the switch leg black to the other hots and marking the returning white with tape? Then connect white and pretend black to the fixture as usual?

Thanks in advance everyone
[image]

Comment: Neutral must be white.  Quite often, switch loops, white is not neutral.  The white should be marked with red/black as a hot/live wire, but 8 times out of ten people are lazy.  Quite common before smart switches that white was used as hot to the switch and the black from the switch was switch hot. it saved a lot of copper wire since switches did not need/used neutral.

Comment: That was what I have been led to believe, however, in the attached pic, I don't see where this switch loop is tied to black (hot) at all?

Comment: Before we get confused, where are you?  I see a lot of brown wires, but only one short black and one short white.  Most cable systems use a hot colour/s and their neutral colours(black and white, red and blue) in cables.

Comment: SouthEast US. I think age has taken its toll on the whites. I think they probably started out life as white wires. There are only white (very yellowed/brown), black, and bare copper in there. The wire jacket hasn't aged well either I have noticed in the attic.

Comment: The "brown" wires are aged whites.

Comment: aside: it's "by accident", compared to "on purpose". thank my english teacher mom...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does look wrong.  Is it as easy as swapping a connection?  That depends whether this box is the only one wired wrong.  It would be sufficient to use a multimeter to verify the black-to-ground voltage around 120 VAC and white-to-ground is zero, so that you're sure the white wires aren't live.  Remember to turn off the circuit breaker after testing.

> marking the returning white with tape

Don't do that.  NEC 200.7(C) allows the white wire "be used only for the supply to the switch."  You should mark it but you can't use it as a return wire.

Comment: "Don't use white as a return switched wire" Learn something new every day. Thank you

Comment: You should mention that current versions of the NEC **require** re-marking the repurposed white wires in all cases now. At some point in the past, re-marking was not mandatory, but now it is.